Airflow dbt workflow run failed in docker
I'm totally new to apache airflow and dbt. I'm running airflow on docker and when I tried to run the dbt demo workflow, I get this error. I've managed to run the dbt model on my local. Any idea what causes the error?
[2024-09-27, 14:50:45 UTC] {subprocess.py:69} INFO - Running command: ['/usr/local/airflow/dbt_venv/bin/dbt', 'run', '--models', 'my_first_dbt_model', '--project-dir', '/tmp/tmp943gjfck', '--profiles-dir', '/tmp/cosmos/profile/1d390e975d9ea414ab43ddd449486c885400dd6be3d9c4b702d12711ab61e6e4', '--profile', 'default', '--target', 'dev']
[2024-09-27, 14:50:45 UTC] {subprocess.py:80} INFO - Command output:
[2024-09-27, 14:50:46 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:46  Running with dbt=1.8.7
[2024-09-27, 14:50:46 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:46  Registered adapter: clickhouse=1.8.4
[2024-09-27, 14:50:46 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:46  Unable to do partial parsing because profile has changed
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:47  Found 2 models, 4 data tests, 574 macros
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:47
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:47
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:47  Finished running  in 0 hours 0 minutes and 0.21 seconds (0.21s).
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - 14:50:47  Encountered an error:
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO - Database Error
[2024-09-27, 14:50:47 UTC] {subprocess.py:90} INFO -   Unexpected EOF while reading bytes
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {subprocess.py:94} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {local.py:286} INFO -   Unexpected EOF while reading bytes
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {local.py:196} WARNING - Artifact schema version: https://schemas.getdbt.com/dbt/manifest/v12.json is above dbt-ol supported version 7. This might cause errors.
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {local.py:389} INFO - Inlets: []
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {local.py:390} INFO - Outlets: []
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {dag.py:3239} INFO - Sync 1 DAGs
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {dag.py:4180} INFO - Setting next_dagrun for dbt_dag to 2024-09-27 00:00:00+00:00, run_after=2024-09-28 00:00:00+00:00
[2024-09-27, 14:50:48 UTC] {local.py:193} ERROR - 14:50:46  Running with dbt=1.8.7

Tried with different combinations on the connection setup, still get the same errors. I think I got my credentials set properly.

Facing then same issue, how were you able to fix it.
